# Insert New HTML Input Tag in td with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to insert new HTML Input Tag in td for Text.My Leader said me not to use jquery and other plugins so, I think that can be only Javascript.I want to insert new Input tag for all td in table. How can I insert New HTML Input Tag??? Pls Help Me
!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var btn_name=document.getElementsByName("submitConfirm");
function init()
{
    document.getElementsByName("submitConfirm").onClick=function()
    {
    Edit_td();
    }
}
function Edit_td()
{

}
```

`window.onload(init());`

That's my prepared code.

Comment: show your markup also? and I didn't get what do you mean by `only element name` please specify.

Comment: "submitConfirm" is name of Input.I can handle that but I don't know how to insert Input tag within td when click the button

Comment: when you function `init` is getting called ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot that, I call that from window.onload

Comment: I've updated my answer for your problem. try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this, should work for you :-

```
function editTd() {
    var rows = document.getElementById('tbl1').rows;
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var row = rows[i];
        for (var j = 0; j < row.cells.length; j++) {
            var input = document.createElement('input');
            input.type = "text";
            row.cells[j].appendChild(input);
        };
    };
}

window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementsByName("submitConfirm")[0].onclick = editTd;
};
```

This is my markup

```
<button name="submitConfirm">submit</button>
<table id="tbl1">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var td = document.querySelector('td') // or getElementById/ClassName[0]  

var input = document.createElement('input')
input.type = 'text' // or other

td.appendchild(input)
```

Comment: In my Web page,that has other td from other table so that will be affect all, isn't it?how can I take td from my target table.I can only use table ID...

Comment: put here your html, without that i cant help you

Comment: you can do
var table = document.getElementById('table-id')
var td = table.querySelector('td')

Comment: I can't touch html too.He give me table id other tag name.I can run to see output.I can see only tags from Mozilla Inspector . That's all. I'm sorry

Comment: That will be great :D